# Compiling Opencv cpp code in ubuntu

Tags: compiling, c++, opencv, linux-headers

while compiling the below code..

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 string imageName("../Desktop/image.jpeg"); // by default
 if( argc > 1)
 {
 imageName = argv[1];
 }

 Mat image;

 image = imread(imageName.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

 if( image.empty() ) // Check for invalid input
 {
 cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
 return -1;
 }

 namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.

 imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

 waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
 return 0;
}
```

the following error has been occured..

```
hello.cpp:2:33: fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-file list libopencv-imgcodecs-dev
```

maybe you need to install "apt-file" first:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt update
```

apt-file may show you the correct path. In this case it should be:

```
  #include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo apt install libopencv-dev`. If the dev package is not installed you won't have any opencv headers.